# asp.net, use a server cert to make httpwebrequest C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, https, iis-6, certificate

Sorry this is my first post and I'll try and be as descriptive as possible...

I am having an issue converting an HTTPWebRequest to reach an HTTPS website that requires a certificate. On my local dev machine I can create the web request to the site by using my client certificate from my CAC card using a CAC card reader. My problem arises when I have to push this code to our dev/prod server to access this site. I cant read my CAC card when I am on the server but I do have a server cert that I can use that is on our IIS 6.0.

Can you get the client's CAC card cert on the server? Is there a store to look from? Or is there a server store to look from?

I dont know the steps to using this server cert, whether I have to code this or work with my IIS Server Manager to enable it. This is my code on my local dev machine that is working. I added the ServerCertficateValidationCallback to test on the dev server.

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   { 
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);

        ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 300000;

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://url");
        request.Accept = "text/xml, */*";
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-us");
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; .NET CLR 3.5.30729;)";
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        request.KeepAlive = false;

        X509Certificate myCert = null;
        X509Store store = new X509Store("My");

        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        int i = 0;
        foreach (X509Certificate2 m in store.Certificates)
        {
             if (i == 0)
                myCert = m;
             i++;
        }

        if (myCert != null)
        {
             request.ClientCertificates.Add(myCert);
        }

        //take the response and create the xml document to parse
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string str = reader.ReadToEnd();

        ...
        }

        public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate,X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            //certificate is in here
            if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
               return true;

            sslPE = "SSLPolicyErros: " + sslPolicyErrors;

            return false;
        }
```

Is anyone familiar with the process, for deployment, to use that server cert that is trusted by the web site im sending a request to? I want all users who access this site from our site ( our site requires CAC authentication ) to use the server cert. Unless someone has a better idea of using the users client certificate from their CAC card. I am having trouble putting this all together and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The root ca (issuer) of your (CAC) certificate must be trusted by your server. Add the root ca certificate to the trusted root certification authority section of the windows certificate store of your server and restart iis.